# WPF - PenIMC.dll missing module

Tags: visual-studio-2015, hid

I'm going out of my mind! Because of MS updates, my VS 2015 is crashing ALL THE TIME and I have to restart my Lenovo every 5-10 mins.

I've searched for the error of Missing PenIMC.dll module not found and everyone says it has something to do with .NET 4.7. However I'm on a shitty LTSB branch where .NET 4.6.1 is the last update I can have, so I know it isn't because of .NET 4.7.

Do you have any ideas? Please help :-) Thanks in advance.

Best regards
Jens

Comment: remove last windows install updates and install .net 4.7 on your own. reboot and run WU to reinstall last Cumulative update. Ms now includes 4.6 and 4.7 file in updates and this may cause issues.

Comment: also try the new [.net 4.7.1](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=56116)